# How to create a timeline chart control thing?

Tags: c#, winforms, charts, filenames, timeline

I am trying to create a timeline, and have been trying to use chart control. but it is not working out as i only need the X value and the chart series is like, only AddY or AddXY, there's no AddX/AddXX2.

I know there's like, questions like this before and stuff. There's this person that asked

> How to create a timeline control?

like, 3 years ago but i'm not sure what exactly they are saying in the answers and comments..

My current code is:

```
 DirectoryInfo dInfo = new DirectoryInfo(tbSelectFolder.Text);
        FileInfo[] Files = dInfo.GetFiles("*.ts");
        List<string> fileNames = new List<string>();

        List<DateTime> fileDates = new List<DateTime>();


        chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.MajorGrid.LineColor = Color.White;
        chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.MajorGrid.LineColor = Color.White;
        chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.MajorGrid.LineDashStyle = ChartDashStyle.Solid;
        chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.MajorGrid.LineDashStyle = ChartDashStyle.Dash;
        chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.LabelStyle.ForeColor = Color.White;
        chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.LabelStyle.ForeColor = Color.White;
        chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX2.Enabled = AxisEnabled.True;

        foreach (FileInfo file in Files)
        {
            string filename = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(file.Name);
            string[] fileNameSplit = filename.Split(' ');
            fileNames.Add(fileNameSplit[0]);

            DateTime date = DateTime.ParseExact(fileNameSplit[1], "yyMMdd",null);
            fileDates.Add(date);
        }


        foreach (var value in fileNames)
        {
            foreach (var value1 in fileDates)
            {
                chart1.Series["US"].Points.AddXY(value1, value); 
            }
        }
```

This basically gives me this

[image: Lame Looking Chart]

The timeline i'm trying to create is basically like a time table. So, is there a way to make it look something like this

[image: What i Want]

[image]

Comment: Your chart _thing_ looks like a column chart. What chart type are you using?

Comment: I was using either a line or bar chart. I was contemplating stacked bar chart but idk how to do that cause I can't seem to auto add series. Tho it's prob possible to add by the Series series = new Series(); I think?

Comment: You may want to improve the image of what you want a little to make it clearer. It certainly does not look like a timeline at all to me. Will the shown part have to have different sizes? what are those numbers? dates??

Comment: Sorry cause i dont have an actual image of what i want so i used Word. Does this picture seem clearer?

Comment: So you want to list filenames and dates? Creation dates or some other date you can get from the FileInfo class? Or from the filename? Well it is certainly doable, but hav you thought about the space such a timeline will take? Theere is alinit of what you can show (32k pixels) and user will not like even that.. Maybe a vertical listing would be better..? Or how many file names do expect to show?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a possible solution:

[image]

```
    // set up from clean slate:
    chart1.ChartAreas.Clear();
    chart1.Series.Clear();
    ChartArea CA = chart1.ChartAreas.Add("CA");
    Series S1 = chart1.Series.Add("S1");
    S1.ChartType = SeriesChartType.Column;  // whatever..

    // a few restriction for my own files:
    CA.AxisX.Maximum = new DateTime(2014, 12, 31).ToOADate();
    DirectoryInfo dInfo = new DirectoryInfo("D:\\");
    FileInfo[] Files = dInfo.GetFiles("f*.png");

    // staying with the file info list!
    //List<string> fileNames = new List<string>();
    //List<DateTime> fileDates = new List<DateTime>();

    chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.MajorGrid.LineColor = Color.White;
    chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.MajorGrid.LineColor = Color.White;
    chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.MajorGrid.LineDashStyle = ChartDashStyle.Solid;
    chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.MajorGrid.LineDashStyle = ChartDashStyle.Dash;
    chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.LabelStyle.ForeColor = Color.White;
    chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.LabelStyle.ForeColor = Color.White;
    chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX2.Enabled = AxisEnabled.True;

    S1.IsValueShownAsLabel = true;
    S1.LabelFormat = "YYY.MM";

    // restrict to 20 files max:
    for (int i = 0; i < Math.Min(20, Files.Length); i++)
    {
        FileInfo FI = Files[i];
        int p = chart1.Series[0].Points.AddXY(FI.CreationTime, 1);
        S1.Points[p].Label = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(FI.FullName);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope this fits your needs: unfortunately the axis-label aren't perfect, thats why you can remove them completely by uncommenting the first three line of code .

```
//Just pass your list of dates to this function
private void DrawTimeline(List<DateTime> dates)
{

    //chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.MajorGrid.LineColor = Color.Black;
    //chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.MajorGrid.LineColor = Color.White;
    //chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.LabelStyle.Enabled = false;
    chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.IsStartedFromZero = false;

    //initialize a legend with some settings
    chart1.Legends.Clear();
    chart1.Legends.Add("Timespans");
    chart1.Legends[0].LegendStyle = LegendStyle.Table;
    chart1.Legends[0].Docking = Docking.Bottom;
    chart1.Legends[0].Alignment = StringAlignment.Center;
    chart1.Legends[0].Title = "Timespans";
    chart1.Legends[0].BorderColor = Color.Black;

    chart1.Series.Clear();
    string seriesname;
    //adding the bars with some settings
    for (int i = 0; i < dates.Count-1; i++)
    {
        seriesname = Convert.ToString(dates[i].Date + " - " + dates[i + 1].Date);
        chart1.Series.Add(seriesname);
        chart1.Series[seriesname].ChartType = SeriesChartType.RangeBar;
        chart1.Series[seriesname].YValuesPerPoint = 2;
        chart1.Series[seriesname].Points.AddXY("Timeline", dates[i].Date, dates[i + 1].Date);
        chart1.Series[seriesname]["DrawSideBySide"] = "false";
        chart1.Series[seriesname].BorderColor = Color.Black;
        chart1.Series[seriesname].ToolTip = seriesname;
    }
}
```