# Create a timeline in windows forms

Tags: c#, winforms

I can't put the different scenario throughout the timeline(X-ais). I mean the different scenario(different color in timeline chart) can not be repeated in different period of time for each machine(Y-axis).

I want to make the timeline chart as in a 2nd picture. The information which I want to show in timeline chart are as the following;

1. X-axis : show the timeline throughout the day
2. Y-axis : show different machine in the factory
3. Different color in chart: show different scenario in the production line or the status of each machine includes; run, Alarm, wait and off. that can be changed throughout a day.

I have tired so many time to make this timeline chart by using Microsoft control but the result which I could get was showed in 1st pic.

```
 public Form1()
            {
                InitializeComponent();
                chart1.Titles.Add("Stacked BAR Chart !");


            chart1.Series["RUN"].Points.AddXY("MACHINE 1", "50");
            chart1.Series["ALARM"].Points.AddXY("MACHINE 1", "30");
            chart1.Series["WAIT"].Points.AddXY("MACHINE 1", "10");
            chart1.Series["OFF"].Points.AddXY("MACHINE 1", "10");

            chart1.Series["RUN"].Points.AddXY("MACHINE 2", "250");
            chart1.Series["ALARM"].Points.AddXY("MACHINE 2", "150");
            chart1.Series["WAIT"].Points.AddXY("MACHINE 2", "70");
            chart1.Series["OFF"].Points.AddXY("MACHINE 2", "200");

            chart1.Series["RUN"].Points.AddXY("MACHINE 3", "50");
            chart1.Series["ALARM"].Points.AddXY("MACHINE 3", "150");
            chart1.Series["WAIT"].Points.AddXY("MACHINE 3", "150");
            chart1.Series["OFF"].Points.AddXY("MACHINE 3", "400");

            chart1.Series["RUN"].Points.AddXY("MACHINE 4", "250");
            chart1.Series["ALARM"].Points.AddXY("MACHINE 4", "150");
            chart1.Series["WAIT"].Points.AddXY("MACHINE 4", "750");
            chart1.Series["OFF"].Points.AddXY("MACHINE 4", "200");


            chart1.Series["RUN"].Points.AddXY("MACHINE 5", "250");
            chart1.Series["ALARM"].Points.AddXY("MACHINE 5", "50");
            chart1.Series["WAIT"].Points.AddXY("MACHINE 5", "170");
            chart1.Series["OFF"].Points.AddXY("MACHINE 5", "20");


            }
```

Could you please guide me how to make the timeline chart for each machine which will show 4 different scenario throughout the day. I mean each scenario can be happen again throughout the time for each machine.

this is 1st picture
[image]

this is 2nd picture
[image]

Comment: Download the msdn examples.  gives 1000 examples and options : https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Samples-Environments-for-b01e9c61

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34099055/1563833) suggests using a RangeBar chart type and setting "DrawSideBySide" = "false";

Answer (score 0):

I would like to say thank you for your all comment that brings the way to find the solution.

the solution are

1. : download sample chart link from jdweng and learning about Rangebar chart.
2. : you will see the solution is Rangebar chart and setting "DrawSideBySide" = "fase" and more.
3. : jdweng and Wyck . you guys are good helper.